# What equipment do I need for a 5 days kayak journey in the Mediterranean Sea?

Tags: kayaks

I am planning to do a 5 days journey on a kayak with a friend. I have a 4.9m plastic sit on top kayak and we were planning to start from [Tropea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropea) on the so called ["costa degli dei"](http://www.lacostabella.com/calabria/) ("Coast of the Gods"), and make our way down to [Reggio Calabria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Province_of_Reggio_Calabria). On average 15-18 nautical miles per day is planned.

Since this is our first multi-day journey I would love to hear some advice especially related to security. What supplies, tools, radios and all these things are required for instance. We are planning to do it in summer and summer in the south of Italy is extremely hot.

We are trained and able to row for hours without stopping. We know basic security measures and practice and the nautical code as well.

Comment: Don't underestimate what you are taking on here. The area is notorious for sudden unexpected storms, and there are long sections of rocky coast without any shelter.

Comment: What specific make and model kayak do you have

Comment: I know the area and you are right. There are few long section of rocks without any places to dock. My kayak is a samblas dolphin (http://i62.tinypic.com/2qddidg.jpg). The good thing is that the area is crowded during summer so there will always be boats  of tourists around.